# D3 radial tree custom edit circle cytoscape.js-cise-master

Tags: javascript, json, cytoscape.js

I am using the [cytoscape.js-cise](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-cise/blob/master/demo.html) layout:

[image]

I need the output to look like this :

- I need to differentiate the nodes by their color, which means that nodes of one color will be in their own circle

I have 10 different colors so i need to create 10 circles.
The desired layout should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to get rid of the colors (second image is your goal??)? Do you want to import the layout to D3 (question title is confusing)? Do you want to get the nodes to group like the example in the cytoscape.js-cise-layout does?